# InputMismatchException in LOOP

Tags: java, inputmismatchexception

I tried to find a solution for my problem, but couldn't find one that worked in practice. So please, if YOU'RE NOT SURE you know what the solution is, don't answer. I really need concrete help.

The problem is that when I run my simple code - you can pick a number and it's ok, loop is working fine. When you pick 0, it works too (run is finished), but when you put a letter or any string - there's a problem... an exception keeps looping without stop, even if I try inputting another value.

PS. I need to use Scanner here so please don`t write about readers etc. - just how to solve this specific problem.

Cheers,

Here's code (only main):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO code application logic here
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int dane = -1 ;

     boolean keepLooping;   //if you delete this works the same with same problem
do  
{    
    keepLooping = false;
    try
    {

            System.out.println("Pick a number:");
            dane = sc.nextInt();


    }catch (InputMismatchException e)
      {
          System.out.println("Your exception is: " + e);
          keepLooping = false;
      }  
    System.out.println("Out from exception");

}while ((dane != 0)||(keepLooping == true));   

}
```

Comment: actually its NumberFormatException which must be catched not InputMismatch. read this http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/NumberFormatException.html

Comment: where are you setting keepLooping to true??

Comment: If `keepLooping` is not relevant to the problem, it should not be in the problem description. More importantly, what is your test input, and what is the exception?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO code application logic here
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int dane = -1 ;

     boolean keepLooping = true;   //if you delete this works the same with same problem
while(keepLooping && dane != 0)  
{    

    System.out.println("Pick a number:");
try
{ 

        dane = Integer.parseInt(sc.next());


}catch (NumberFormatException e)
  {
       keepLooping = true;
  }  
System.out.println("Out from exception");

}
```

Comment: Thank for help, but it`s still working like almost the same. After handle exception it stop working. I used exception that after handle exception to stay in loop. EG.: after when i put string, app should return exception and ask for other value. If you put 0 then it stops if number it continue the loop.

Comment: run:
Pick a number:
1
Pick a number:
s
Out from exception
Your exception is: java.util.InputMismatchException
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 6 seconds)
----still the same. && nothing helped. After exception it stopped. I need continue from this place where next step is back to loop.

Comment: it's output on my maching Out from exception
Pick a number:
w
Out from exception
Pick a number:
w
Out from exception
Pick a number:
w
Out from exception
Pick a number:
w
Out from exception
Pick a number:
w
Out from exception
Pick a number:
w

Comment: I told you it's NumberFormatException, not InputMismatchException.
Catch this line dane = Integer.parseInt(sc.next());
This line makes sure that whatever you enter gets parsed into int, if it can't it throws NumberFormatException

Answer (score 0):

**Edited**

Do like this

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int dane = -1 ;

         boolean keepLooping;   //if you delete this works the same with same problem
    do  
    {    
        keepLooping = false;
        try
        {

                System.out.println("Pick a number:");
                dane = sc.nextInt();


        }catch (InputMismatchException e)
          {
              System.out.println("Your exception is: " + e);
              keepLooping = false;
              dane = sc.nextInt();
          }  
        System.out.println("Out from exception");

    }while ((dane != 0)||(keepLooping == true)&&(dane!=0));   

    }
```

Comment: checked this option earlier - didn`t help

Comment: no, it`s not working. All i need is after handle exception pick another value number - then loop again, if string - exception and bask asking for loop, if 0 then stop running.

Comment: i re-check that. Now it looks like it raise exception. Adis solution solved my problem, but thank you for trying ;)

Answer (score 0):

Problem is when you say -

dane = sc.nextInt();

in the above line if you give an input of anything else than a number it will throw an exception input mismatch.
Lets understand what this line does. actually two things -

first sc.nextInt() reads an integer and only on successfull completion of this task it will assign that integer value to variable dane. but while reading an integer it throws an InputMismatchException so the assignment never happened and yet dane has it's previos value not the new one which scanner read so dane is still not equals to 0.
so the loop continues.

I hope it helps.

Comment: I`m glad that you understood this "complicated" code. Any solution maybe? Just please don`t put here what do you think or not. I need concrete. If you didn`t check it or not sure - don`t write only because you can ;)